# Prestashop 1.6: Place "User Info Block" module (User Login block) next to the "Cart Block"

Tags: module, hook, block, prestashop, userinfo

I'm using default theme in Prestashop 1.6.
Is there a way to move the "User Info Block" module (User loging/logout) from "DislayNav" hook to "DisplayTop" hook just above the main menu and between Quick search and Cart block. The module is actually already hooked in this position but for some reason it doesn't show even after I unhooked it from its initial position which is the "DisplayNav" hook !

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall the User Info Block module transplant to DisplayTop.

Comment: I re-installed it and hooked it to DisplayTop, But it is still showing in displayNav next to "language Block" and "contact Block" and not between "Quick search Block" and "Cart Block" like I want it !